Stick welder polarity
Can anyone tell does stick welder (in general) has limitation on weather it can weld dc positive or dc negative (stick holder being positive or negative).
Or it all comes to exchange of electrode holder and piece holder clamp.
For example Miller STH 160 say that for dc stick welding you should connect clamp to positive and workpiece to negative terminal.
Also why some stick welder say specifically they can weld cellulose electrodes like EWM Pico 160 CEL plus.
https://www.ewm-sales.com/en/MMA_welding_machines--6422.html
Does it mean that for example Miller 160 STH cannot weld cellulose electrode ?
Thank you for helping in advance!!

Most Welders have a switch to select polarity (or AC).  Your example seems to do this by plugging the electrode and clamp into the right output terminals.

Having the electrode positive or negative affects the heat in the weld.
Something to try - especially with different materials.
